# Дата в php и замена на текущий год

Tags: php

Подскажите как правильно изменить год на текущий в дате.
Побывал так, но не выходит, меняет все на 2020-**01**-**01**

```
$y = date("Y")
$idatd = date("$y-m-d" ,$row['start']);
```

Comment: что внутри `$row['start']`? 2020 - текущий. и вам надо поменять на текущий. что не так?

Comment: почитайте про формат второго аргумента date: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$originalDate = strtotime('2011-04-04');
$fixedDate = strtotime(date('Y') . date('-m-d', $originalDate));
print(date('Y-m-d', $newDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$Minus = strtotime('-1 year');// Вычитаем год из текущего времени
$Date = date('Y-m-d', $Minus); // Преобразовываем в удобочитаемый вид 
print_r($Date); // Выводим на экран
```